# Calculating riveting force

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fasteners, rivets

How do you calculate the force required to form a tubular riveted joint? Assume the tubular rivet's ID, OD, and initial and final length and diameters as variables.

Comment: What sort of rivet? shear point of the shaft? Or the mass & velocity of the sledge?

Comment: Tubular rivet. Its already mentioned in the question. If you meant what process, then consider an impact riveting.

Comment: It's not an impact riveting process exactly. The ram engages with the rivet first and then gradually applies load until the rivet is formed. You can assume other parameters. Not exactly sure what a shear point is.

Comment: So tubular... ok, normal rivet or blind?

Comment: a normal rivet.

Comment: Ok, so now what material? aluminum? Copper? Iron? Steel?

Comment: Does that matter? I just need an expression or a procedure to calculate the force. Not the actual value of force. Proceed with assuming variables for the necessary quantities as mentioned in the question.